# Console output into text file

Tags: java, eclipse, outputstream

code to convert HTML file to .txt file. code for reference..

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:/ticket.htm"));
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }
    String nohtml = sb.toString().replaceAll("\\<.*?>", "");
    String nospace = nohtml.replaceAll(
            "^\\s+|\\s+$|\\s*(\n)\\s*|(\\s)\\s*", "$1$2");
    String new1 = nospace.replace("\t", " ");
    System.out.println(new1);
    PrintWriter outs = new PrintWriter("D:/text123.txt");
    outs.write(new1);
    outs.println(new1);
    outs.close();
}
```

`new1` contains text(HTML output) which I am able to print line by line in the eclipse console,
but when am trying to copy that text into text file (`text123.txt`), the text is copied in the same line.

I need to same console output to be copied in the text file i.e line by line.

Comment: What is the purpose of `outs.write(new1);` if you are also using `outs.println(new1);` to add text from `new1` to file?

Comment: Can you provide `new1` `String`?

Comment: What happens if you remove `write` and use only `println`?

Comment: @Pshemo the output is same .

Comment: Consider posting code which will let us reproduce your problem. Show us some example input, output in console and in file. Otherwise we can only guess what is wrong with your code.

Comment: @Pshemo The entire code is copied. As far HTML is concerned you can use a simple plain HTML file.

Comment: Include example of input, actual output and expected one with little explanation of why such output would be expected.

Comment: Can you give example of the expected output in the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this out

```
String new1 = "Some text";
PrintWriter outs;
try {
    outs = new PrintWriter("D:/text123.txt");
    outs.write(new1 + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    outs.write(new1 + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    outs.write(new1 + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    outs.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're calling both "write" and "println" methods of the PrintWriter object.

The println() call will add \n which is a newline character after whatever string you give it.

Comment: even though i comment write method and execute with only println. it is giving the same output.